# My Buttons are not set at the center with same size

Tags: java, jframe, size, jbutton, box

I have 3 buttons and each button does some functionality I have used BOX to created these buttons.
Each button has been set to different size based on the text in them.
I want all button to have same size.

I tried using `preferredSize()` but It did not make any change.
Below is my sample code.

```
public class MyMain extends JPanel {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
static JButton jbt1 = new JButton("Button1");
static JButton jbt2 = new JButton("Button2");
static JButton jbt3 = new JButton("Button3");
static JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(2, 10);
static JTextArea OutputFormat = new JTextArea(2, 20);
static JTextArea OtherFormat = new JTextArea(2, 20);
static JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);

public MyMain() {
    Box box = Box.createVerticalBox();
    textArea.setText("WELCOME TO CREATOR");
    OutputFormat.setText("Some Text here");
    OtherFormat.setText("Some More Text Here ");
    box.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(10));
    box.add(OutputFormat);
    box.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(20));
    box.add(OtherFormat);
    box.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(20));
    box.add(jbt1);
    box.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(20));
    box.add(jbt2);
    box.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(20));
    box.add(jbt3);
    box.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(5));
    box.add(textArea);
    box.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(10));
    add(box);
}

public static void createAndShowGui() {
    JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("TRANSLATOR");
    SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(frame);
    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.green);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(500, 350);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.add(new PBIFile());
    frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    frame.setLocation(dim.width / 2 - frame.getSize().width / 2, dim.height / 2 - frame.getSize().height / 2);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
        }
    });
    textArea.setEditable(false);
    textArea.setLineWrap(true);
    jbt1.addActionListener(new Action1());
    jbt2.addActionListener(new Action2());
    jbt3.addActionListener(new Action3());  
}

static class Action1 implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    }
}

static class Action2 implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    }
}

static class Action3 implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    }
}
```

}

Can someone please help me set the button size constant for all the buttons.
Currently I am seeing each button with different size based on the number of characters in the name of the button.

Comment: Code does not compile - `PBIFormat` is undefined. Post a [mcve].

Comment: @user1803551 Hi Sorry. thanks for the reply I have changed the code. Can you please look into this and reply back.

Comment: Exactly same compilation error.